# How to change font size of numerical value of a slider parameter in Manipulate[Plot]?

Tags: manipulate

I start with the very simple Manipulate of a Plot:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[omega*x],{x,0,5*Pi}],{omega,0,3}]
```

I know how to customize a bit the slider, so as to have it labeled with the name of the parameter omega, on the left of the slider, in a larger font size:

```
Manipulate[ Plot[Sin[omega*x], {x, 0, 5*Pi}], {{omega, 0, Style["\[Omega]", 16]}, 0, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

However, this last modification shows, on the right of the slider, the current numerical value of the parameter omega too small, not corresponding to the FontSize 16 of the label  omega itself, on the left of the slider. I would like something like (of course does not work):

```
Manipulate[ Plot[Sin[omega*x], {x, 0, 5*Pi}], {{omega, FontSize[0, 16], Style["\[Omega]", 16]}, 0, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

How can I change the font size of the current displayed value for the parameter on the slider???

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the option `LabelStyle`

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[omega*x], {x, 0, 5*Pi}], {{omega, 0, Style["\[Omega]", 25]},0, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled", LabelStyle -> (*Large *)   {Red, FontSize -> 25}   }]
```

[image]

Comment: Your first suggestion (with LabelStyle -> Large) worked, but the font size was way too large now... Your second suggestion (with FontSize->16) caused no change at all in the right hand side number of the slider:

Comment: Did you try for example `LabelStyle -> {Red, FontSize -> 25}` See my edited answer!

Comment: Excuse me: I got the syntax wrong for the second suggestion. I tried: Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[omega*x], {x, 0, 5*Pi}], {{omega, 0, Style["\[Omega]", 16]},
   0, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled", FontSize -> 16}] instead of the correct: Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[omega*x], {x, 0, 5*Pi}], {{omega, 0, Style["\[Omega]", 16]},
   0, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled", LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 16}}] This last one does work. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Magic grammar :), how do you know this?